# RFC2047 Conversion Issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am making a GMail add-on in Google Apps Scripts and I come across an issue with emails not in ASCII encoding. I tried converting the portions that look like `=?us-ascii?Q?a*data=3DBaUd8g06EDNqzYX7LSepWIJnDYVzU7yu?=` using `Utilities.newBlob(rawCont).getDataAsString("us-ascii"))`; however, this provides no avail. Is there a native Javascript way to do this or a way to do this in Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: `=?us-ascii?Q?a*data=3DBaUd8g06EDNqzYX7LSepWIJnDYVzU7yu?=` what the text it should be? Btw, technically all these characters are ascii characters.

Comment: @YuriKhristich `a*data=BaUd8g06EDNqzYX7LSepWIJnDYVzU7yu` the characters are ascii but its an encoded ASCII under RFC 2047